# BC30554: 'ProfileCommon' is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, asp.net-profiles

I use asp.net user management in my Website.(ASP.NET 3.5) Everything has been working fine while developing and test via VS2010 on Win7. But when I compile and publish the site throws the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30554: 'ProfileCommon' is ambiguous.

Line 55:         End Sub
Line 56:         
Line 57:         Protected ReadOnly Property Profile() As ProfileCommon
Line 58:             Get
Line 59:                 Return CType(Me.Context.Profile,ProfileCommon)
```

please help me. thanks

Comment: Is that the full compiler message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a forum where someone was having what appears to be a similar problem as you:

http://forums.asp.net/t/986390.aspx/1

It is an older question, but some of the answers they have discussed might give you a place to start looking.

Comment: I tested all of solutions that was in this page but my problem not solved :(

Answer (score 1):

Try solution from [this](http://gregorybeamer.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/solving-the-profilecommon-ambiguous-error/) article.

Basically remove the "properties" from your config file and build the application. It will bring an error. After that add back you "properties" section in config and it must start work.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted All Deployed files(required App only) from IIS and deployed again to IIS worked for me.